# tracking camera's position and rotation

Tags: ios, camera, scenekit

I have **allowsCameraControl** property set to true. I need my camera to tell me what it's position and rotation is, while I move it around with pinch and pan gestures so I can later update my camera to that position. Is there some function that is called every rendering moment so I can put **println:** statement in it? The other option I could think was to set a **didSet** statement at camera's position and rotation property but I have no idea how to do that if I'm not the one defining the property in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way around it using custom buttons(moveLeft,moveRight,rotateLeft etc..) to move the camera(and report current position) around 3D space. Works great. Can't tell if mnuages's suggestion works, but it looks allright.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delegation methods such as `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`'s `-renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:` and you can access the "free" camera by using the view's `pointOfView`.

Comment: thanks for answering. I already found a way around it using custom buttons(moveLeft,moveRight,rotateLeft etc..) to move the camera(and report current position) around 3D space.